# To Create single product as both simple and downloadable products

Tags: products, downloadable

I want to publish a book in both format(i.e papaer back hard copy as well as downloadable). Is there any solution for it? Please do the needful. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you will create one product as a `Simple Product` and other a `Downloadable Product` and that's it, provide all the required info e.g. downloadable file and/or sample. If using M1 here's the [further read](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-downloadable.html) and for M2 [read here](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-downloadable.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. But I want the same book in both format using same SKU. Is it possible? If yes, please tell me the solution.